# How do I save different Textfield values without creating endless TextEditingController

Tags: flutter, text, controller, uitextfield, textfield

I am working on a ToDo app an am trying to create five Text() widgets that hold the value of one TextformField(). I don't want to create lots of controllers, because the user is able to add more ToDo-fields through the press of a button. I always encounter the problem, that all Text() widgets hold the same string. Does anyone have an idea how I could store different strings through one TextEditingController and pass it to different Text() widgets in a compact code?

You can see the concept and problem below.

Thank you for helping me out!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to create a widget, which is responsible for one TODO row (contains one `Text` widget and one `TextEditingController`). Then, instead of adding a `Text` widget and a `TextEditingController`, you can add a new instance of your new widget to the list of fields on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code.

```
TextEditingController test = TextEditingController();

Column(
    children: [
      TextField(
        controller: test,
      ),
      RaisedButton(
        child: Text("abc"),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            test.text = test.text + "abc";
          });
        },
      ),
      RaisedButton(
        child: Text("efg"),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            test.text = test.text + "efg";
          });
        },
      )
    ],
  )
```